# duplicate value for resource

Tags: android, dependencies, android-resources, androidx

**I'm getting this error**

```
AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/textColor' with config ''.
```

**after adding this dependency**

```
implementation 'com.jarvanmo:exoplayerview:2.1.3'
```

**this dependency is for viewing video.**

If you want anything more plz comment it.

Comment: you have a duplicate resource: check here: res->values->attrs.xml. 
Or change the name of textColor to something else.

Comment: It has two different version of support library. It is because of transitive support library dependency of exoplayerview. try to exclude support library from exoplayer or compatible version to your targetSDK

Comment: I'm getting this error only in version 2.1.3
I increased the version to 2.1.4 error resolved.